# Is uniroot() confusing the input values in R?

Tags: r, function, math, optimization, linear-algebra

I'm wondering in the following, why when I directly provide the value of `q` (*see* `f2`), `uniroot()` works perfectly fine BUT when instead I provide `q` as a function of other input values `uniroot()` (*see* `f1`) fails?

In the code, everything that has `...1` suffix (e.g., `f1`) relates to when I indirectly provide `q`. And everything that has `...2` suffix (e.g., `f2`) relates to when I directly provide `q`.

My goal is to solve for `df2` such that `y = .15` (correct answer is `~ 336.3956`). (*please just run the entire code below*.)

```
alpha = c(.025, .975); df1 = 3; q = 48.05649 ; peta = .3 # input values

f1 <- function(alpha, q, df1, df2, ncp){    # Objective function (`q` indirectly)
  alpha - suppressWarnings(pf(q = (peta / df1) / ((1 - peta)/df2), df1, df2, 
  ncp, lower.tail = FALSE))
}

f2 <- function(alpha, q, df1, df2, ncp){    # Objective function (`q` directly)
  alpha - suppressWarnings(pf(q = q, df1, df2, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE))
}

ncp1 <- function(df2){                    # root finding
 b <- sapply(c(alpha[1], alpha[2]),     
          function(x) uniroot(f1, c(0, 1e7), alpha = x, q = peta, df1 = df1, df2 = df2)[[1]])

  b / (b + (df2 + 4))
}

ncp2 <- function(df2){                    # root finding
  b <- sapply(c(alpha[1], alpha[2]),     
          function(x) uniroot(f2, c(0, 1e7), alpha = x, q = q, df1 = df1, df2 = df2)[[1]])

 b / (b + (df2 + 4))
}


m1 <- function(df2, y){              # A Utility function
  abs(abs(diff(ncp1(df2))) - y)
}

m2 <- function(df2, y){              # A Utility function
 abs(abs(diff(ncp2(df2))) - y)
}

optimize(m1, c(1, 1e7), y = .15)[[1]] # Incorrect answer: 1e+07

optimize(m2, c(1, 1e7), y = .15)[[1]] # Correct answer: 336.3956
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In `ncp1`**

you have `q = peta` which then gets passed on to `f1` but then does not actually get used, as `pf` takes `q` as `(peta / df1) / ((1 - peta)/df2)`.

**In `ncp2`**

you have `q = peta` which then gets passed on to `f2` and in turn to `pf`.

So the bottom line is you use different values for `q` in `pf`. If you re-active warnings, you will see that `f1` as part of `ncp1` fails to reach convergence.

Comment: @rnorouzian As I said, the issue seems to be the different values for `q` that lead to convergence (method 2) or non-convergence (method 1) when solving for `df2`. From what (little) I understand I can't see anything intrinsically wrong with either methods. `uniroot` just doesn't manage to converge for method 1. So it's not that you get two *different* results; method 2 produces a result while method 1 does not. `uniroot` also uses a fairly crude method (compared to that of `optimize`) so it doesn't surprise me if solutions are not as robust as those from `optimize`.

Comment: @rnorouzian Hmm. I'm not sure I follow. I don't know what you're doing with `optimize` nor what `interval` you are referring to. In `f2` `q` is fixed (as it gets passed down from `ncp2`); in `f1` `q` is (as you say) a function of other parameters, including `df2` for which you're trying to solve. So it seems that these are in fact two *different* functions (and one converges while the other one doesn't).